# Reduce loading time in parse collection view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview, lazy-loading

I am using a collection view to load my images and labels in parse.  I am using the code below.

```
func loadCollectionViewData() {
    // Build a parse query object
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Posts")
    query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    // Check to see if there is a search term
    if searchTextF != "" {
        query.whereKey("imageText", containsString: searchTextF.text)
        //query.whereKey("Tags", containsString: searchTextF.text)
    }

    // Fetch data from the parse platform
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("objects: \(objects)")
        println("error\(error)")

        // The find succeeded now rocess the found objects into the countries array
        if error == nil {

            // Clear existing country data
            tops.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            // Add country objects to our array
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                tops = Array(objects.generate())
            }

            // reload our data into the collection view
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            if self.checkAlert == 0{

                let alert = SCLAlertView()
                alert.showError("Error", subTitle:"An error occured while retrieving your clothes. Please check the Internet connection.", closeButtonTitle:"Ok")
                self.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)

                self.checkAlert = 1

            }

        }

    }
}
```

However with this code, it retrieves all images from parse and takes time to load. I want to reduce the loading time. How do I make it so that so that it would load 10 at at a time and when the user pulls down another 10 is loaded? I was searching all day and couldn't find any resource about this topic in swift. Thank you

Comment: If you have multiple images then you have to check the https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Thank you. Yes I was looking at it but is it ok to use it for swift? However I think even though I use this it will still load the images at once.

Comment: You have to cache the images

Comment: Yes I get it but it still would load the images at once when first loading

Comment: No, It will get it from cache. If you are using SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a PFImageView instead of a UIImageView and load your PFFile using their loadInBackground() method.